# Side-by-side diffs does not work anymore for python files in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, view, diff

For some reason the side by side diff view (working tree) does not work for my python files anymore.
I tried to disable all extensions just in case but it's still the same.
I am on ubuntu 18.04 with VSCode 1.45.1 x64.

Example of working diff view:

[image]

diff view is just not working for python files:

[image]

Is there a setting to enable the diff for specific extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following settings and fixed it:

```
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "default",
            "filenamePattern": "*.py"
        }
    ],
```